# Three.js Sphere into a Cube/ any other shape

Tags: javascript, three.js, panoramas

I am trying to turn a sphere geometry into  a cube geometry in three.js *I am relatively new to this*. I am aware of the subdivision modifier that can take a cube and make a rounded cube but what I want to do is map a texture to a sphere and then stretch that sphere out to fill a cube shape. Is this possible and how would I go converting the sphere into a cube?

Also, I have successfully mapped a 360 pano to 6 sides of a cube but I want it to be mapped to a sphere and then expanded to a cube.

Comment: Do you mean you want to animate the transformation of a sphere into a cube, while maintaining the same texture?

Comment: Not really, I have a 360 video that is mapped as a texture on a sphere. I want that sphere to be expanded into a cube shape while retaining the video texture. Basically a sphere within a cube that expands to fill the cube. No animation just need the final cube with the texture from the sphere. @LarsH

Comment: OK... I'm a bit confused here... your question says "I want it to be mapped to a sphere and then..." but your comment says "I have a 360 video that is mapped as a texture on a sphere." So is it already mapped to a sphere or is it in some other form?

Comment: @LarsH It's already mapped to a sphere but the sphere has to be expanded to take the shape of a cube. Basically this [facebook 360 geometry](https://code.facebook.com/posts/1638767863078802/under-the-hood-building-360-video/)

Comment: So the "facebook 360 geometry" (cubemap) is your goal... and despite the first sentence of your question, I think you're trying to transform the texture, not the geometry. The cube geometry is available as a basic object in Three.js (https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=box#Reference/Geometries/BoxGeometry). Can you give more detail about how your spherical texture is represented? What form is it in?

Comment: https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/index.html thisone? https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Sphere-Unwrapping.html

Comment: Or thisone https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Sphere-Project.html

Comment: @Martin I think the second one is what I'm going for. Does this facilitate the sphere being transformed into the bigger cube?